# For loop issue in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I found below code in JSP at somewhere.

```jsp
  <%
    int cnt =1;
    for(int i=1;i<=iTotalweeks;i++)
    {
    %>
    <tr>
      <% 
        for(int j=1;j<=7;j++)
        {
            if(cnt<weekStartDay || (cnt-weekStartDay+1)>days)
            {
             %>
            <td align="center" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
           <% 
            }
            else
            {
             %>
            <td align="center" height="35" id="day_<%=(cnt-weekStartDay+1)%>"><span><%=(cnt-weekStartDay+1)%></span></td>
           <% 
            }
            cnt++;
          }
        %>
    </tr>
    <% 
    }
    %>
```

Now I'm doing same in Struts2. But I'm stuck in the middle of the coding. How to compare current JSP variable `cnt` with action class's variable.

```jsp
 <s:set var="cnt" value="1" />
    <s:iterator begin="1" end="%{iTotalweeks}">
    <tr>
        <s:iterator begin="1" end="7">

            <s:if test='%{cnt<weekStartDay || (cnt-weekStartDay+1)>days}'>        
            <td align="center" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
           </s:if>
           <s:else>
            <td align="center" height="35"><s:property value="${(cnt-weekStartDay+1)}" /><s:property value="${1}" /></td>
            </s:else>
          <s:set var="cnt" value="${cnt + 1}"/>
          </s:iterator>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
```

In the above code `weekStartDay`, days and `iTotalweeks` are variables in action class and `cnt` is a variable in current JSP.

```java
 public int getDays() {
    return days;
}

public int getWeekStartDay() {
    return weekStartDay;
}

public int getITotalweeks() {
    return iTotalweeks;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of all your <%s and %>s. They should never have been allowed. You don't need bits of Java in your JSP.

Comment: Just use jstl not `<%` tags

Comment: hi,I edited some code using JSTL. But still facing issue.

Comment: If you are using S2 tag for compare then also use S2 tag for settting variable, it would be easy this way.

Comment: But still same issue...

Comment: @sowmyakonduru A few edits and you will fix the issue.

Comment: @roman I unable to do this. I'm new to S2. I'm trying n trying. Even I didn't  get any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `s:if` tag `test` attribute don't use `%{}`.

```
<s:set var="cnt" value="1" />
<s:iterator begin="1" end="%{iTotalweeks}">
<tr>
  <s:iterator begin="1" end="7">
    <s:if test='#cnt<weekStartDay || #cnt-weekStartDay+1>days'>        
    <td align="center" height="35">&nbsp;</td>
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
    <td align="center" height="35"id="day_<s:property value='%{#cnt-weekStartDay+1}'/>"><span><s:property value='%{#cnt-weekStartDay+1}'/></span></td>
    </s:else>
  </s:iterator>
  <s:set var="cnt" value="%{#cnt + 1}"/>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: The Struts 2 iterator tag provides a status attribute which could replace your use of the cnt variable. See the [Iterator documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html) for examples.  This will create a variable of type [IteratorStatus](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) for each iteration.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock yes, you can use a status attribute, but to answer the question you need to compare JSP variable to the action variable. And  show how to create JSP variable using struts2  `s:set` tag.